# How to change the below to variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, process, wmi, cpu

I want to make it so i can select the process and CPU for each of these processes and save them in a variable. For example selecting the first process and saving it as a variable $process1 and $process1CPU

```
$Processes = Get-Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples| Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 5|  ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 0
$process = @("Processes")
$processCpu = @("Process CPU")
Get-Process | ForEach {
  $i++
  $process[$i] = $_.ProcessName
  $processCpu[$i] = (Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples).CookedValue
}
```

Now example if you want to get the Process name 3 use $Process[3] and for its CPU use $ProcessCpu[3]

Comment: The above does not give the correct percentage, it needs to be rounded by each cpu core.

Comment: Ive done lots of it myself? I was just advising the code he sent doesnt work..

Comment: And you've still not rewarded him for his help. ;-)

Comment: "*The above does not give the correct percentage, it needs to be rounded by each cpu core*" is not part of the question, I recommend to open a new question for this if you can't find the answer yourself, taken the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines in consideration.

Comment: iRon and Olaf thank you for your feedback. I take it like my duty. Aaron you can change the CPU part like your own.

Comment: $processes = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | 
    select-object -property Name, @{Name = "CPU"; Expression = {($_.PercentProcessorTime/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)}}, @{Name = "PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}}, @{"Name" = "Memory(MB)"; Expression = {[int]($_.WorkingSetPrivate/1mb)}} |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} |
    Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending|
    Select-Object -First 5